# I am trying to set up jenkins-docker-gitlab pipeline for laravel hello-world project using freestyle project

Tags: docker, nginx

I have a web app running in a docker container at port 9000. I need to route the traffic to Nginx in another container in the same network to access it at port 80. How do I achieve this? I tried building an Nginx image and added Nginx.conf. But my Nginx container stops immediately after it runs.

[contents of Nginx.conf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQvQX.png)

[Snippet of containers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rVAM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind internal port form containers to the host like:

application

```
docker run -d \
    --network=randon_name \
    <image>
```

nginx

You need to bind internal port form containers to the host like:

```
docker run -d \
    --network=randon_name \
    -p 80:80 \    #  <host>:<containerPort>
    -p 443:443 \  #  <host>:<containerPort>
    <image>
```